# Suppose $(S, ∼)$ is an equivalence relation and suppose $a, b ∈ S$. Show $[a] = [b]$ if $a ∼ b$ and $[a] ∩ [b] = ∅$ if $a \not\sim b$.

Tags: relations

I am a bit lost on this question to the point that I don't know where to start. I am confused as to how I am supposed to show this without a defined ~ relation. any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you know the def of [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Definition) ?

Comment: Do you know what $[a]$, the *equivalence set* of $a$, means?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA the relation has to be transitive, symmetric, and reflexive, right? I know the definitions of these 3 terms.

Comment: For the first, assume that $a,b \in S$ and $a \sim b$ and assume for contradiction that $[a] \ne [b]$.

Comment: If $[a] \ne [b]$, this means that for some $z : z \in [a]$ and $z \notin [b]$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp [a] is the set of all _____ that satisfies ~. I am a bit lost on what the _____ should be.

Comment: But from $z \in [a]$ we have that ... ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA z ∈ {b ∈ S | a~b}?

Comment: $[a]$ is the set of all elements of $S$ that are $\sim$ related to $a$.$$[a]=\{s\in S: a\sim s\}$$ So $z\in [a]\to\underline\quad$?

Comment: Yes, but that means : $z \sim a$. And we have : $a \sim b$; thus, by transitivity...

Comment: @GrahamKemp z∈[a]→ {s∈S:a∼s}, is this correct?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA z~b, so then z ∈ [b], ok I see

Comment: Similar for the second : assume that $[a] \cap [b] \ne \emptyset$ that means : for some $z : z \in [a]$ and $z \in [b]$. But $a \nsim b$.

Answer (score 0):

If a ~ b, then for all x,
x in [a] iff x ~ a iff x ~ b iff x in [b].
Thus [a] = [b].

If not a ~ b and x in [a] $\cap$ [b], then
x ~ a and x ~ b, so a ~ b, a contradiction.
Thus [a] $\cap$ [b] is empty.